# NCurses continously update x and y coordinate in moveCursor

Tags: haskell, ncurses

I want to make some sort of game with a snake-like mechanic where you use your arrowkeys to change the coordinate of your snake. But since reassignment of variables isn't a thing in haskell I'm unsure of how to do this. Here is my code:

```
import Control.Monad
import UI.NCurses

main :: IO ()
main = runCurses $ do
    w <- defaultWindow
    forever $ do
        e <- getEvent w Nothing
        updateWindow w $ do
            moveCursor 0 0
            drawString (show e)
        render
```

I want it to print the key pressed (`drawString (show e)`) and then change the cursor to previous x+1, previous y+1, then draw the next key pressed then change the cursor and so on.

How do you do this in NCurses? If reassignment was possible it would be simple, like

```
loop forever:
moveCursor x y
print
x = x+1
y = y+1
```

But reassignment doesn't work so what can I do instead?

Comment: To elaborate on the answer, instead of trying to reassign variables, pass the "modified" states to the next iteration/recurse. Think of `fold`. The accumulator is passed to each successive call as an argument instead of reassigning some variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curse, ncurse, and recurse:

```
loop w x y = do
    e <- getEvent w Nothing
    updateWindow w $ do
        moveCursor x y
        drawString (show e)
    render
    loop w (x+1) (y+1)

main = runCurses $ do
    w <- defaultWindow
    loop w 0 0
```